# Find a parent div id by searching for src results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's sat that im trying to search this code:

```
<div id="ad_creative_1" class="ad-div mastad" style="z-index: 1;">
<script>(function() {var loaded = function() {return yt && yt.www && yt.www.home && yt.www.home.ads;};window.masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround = function() {if (loaded()) {yt.www.home.ads.workaroundIE(this);}};window.masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload = function() {if (!loaded()) {setTimeout(masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload, 50);return;}yt.www.home.ads.workaroundLoad();};})();</script>

      <iframe id="ad_creative_iframe_1" src="http://ad-g.doubleclick.net/N4061/adi/com.ythome/_default;sz=970x250;tile=1;plat=pc;dc_dedup=1;kage=18;kar=3;kbsg=HPUS130404;kcr=us;kga=1001;kgender=m;kgg=1;klg=en;kmyd=ad_creative_1;"
              height="250" width="970"
              scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="z-index: 1"
              onload="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_onload();"
              onmouseover="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround(this)"
              onfocus="masthead_ad_creative_iframe_1_workaround(this)"></iframe>
        <script>
    (function() {
          var ord = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000000);
          var adIframe = document.getElementById("ad_creative_iframe_1");
          adIframe.src = "http://ad-g.doubleclick.net/N4061/adi/com.ythome/_default;sz=970x250;tile=1;plat=pc;dc_dedup=1;kage=18;kar=3;kbsg=HPUS130404;kcr=us;kga=1001;kgender=m;kgg=1;klg=en;kmyd=ad_creative_1;ord=" + ord + "?";
    })();
  </script>

    </div>
```

I want to search within this code for "doubleclick.net", and find the parent div, "ad_creative_1", without knowing the parent div ID.

I have tried this:

```
var container = document.getElementById.$('[src*="doubleclick.net"]').parent().getAttribute('id');
        container.innerHTML = '<center><iframe src="http://somesite.com/" width="478" height="70" scrolling="no" /></center>';
        container.id = "randomshithere";
```

I want to replace out the entire div with container.innerHTML

If i take out the selector, and just put in ad_creative_1 for the getElementId, it works fine and does what I need it to, however the selector is giving me issues as far as actually getting the div ad_creative_1

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the div:

```
var parentDivElement = $('[src*="doubleclick.net"]').closest("div");
parentDivElement.html("<b>Whatever you'd like </b>");
```

Comment: Which part about it didn't work? Did it select the element's parent div?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what it selected, if anything at all.

Comment: Well, use $('[src*="doubleclick.net"]').closest("div").length() , what is it?

Comment: No output. :/ not sure what the hell is going on.

Comment: Contact me on skype? CerviaDeveloper